# How do you read from a node.js website in c#?

Tags: c#, node.js, network-programming

I am having a problem in c#. I have a program that will read data from my node.js website to get data. But when I run the program it reads nothing. I tried the program on google.com(static website) and it worked. What will I have to do?

```
webData = wc.DownloadString("https://log.markratcliffe.repl.co/users/" + textBox1.Text + "password.txt");
```

Comment: Use a sniffer like wiresahrk or fiddler and compare the first request from working and non-working application.  The default headers in c@ are different from js.  Make the headers in c# look like the working app.

Comment: @jdweng I am new to c#, How would I do that?

Comment: You can download wireshark or fiddler for free.   Then start the sniffer before running application.  The IP data will be captured.  You want to view the http packets with the IP address of your client and server.

Comment: @jdweng Thx it worked